# how to make a dtype for list of arrays in numpy python3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-dtype

I have a 300x57 bytes array taken from serial port and shared then I intend to unpickle it directly into numpy array

so I make a dtype with 57 byte size

```
onebuffdtype = np.dtype(
        "b1, b1, f4, u4, u2, u1, f4, u4, u2, u1, f4, i4, i2, i1, f4, u4, u2, u1, f4, u4, u2, u1")
```

then if

```
shared_buff1.buf
```

is place where buffer is located

```
buff1_np = np.ndarray((300, 57,), dtype=onebuffdtype,
                          buffer=shared_buff1.buf)
```

but it says

> TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array

Comment: If your dtype is 57 bytes long, your array of shape should be `(300,)`

Comment: Please add plain tags in the future (I fixed it for you this time). In this case, python and numpy would be the plain tags. There's nothing specific to version 3.6 in your question, even if it's useful to indicate the version you are using.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah thanks,you are right put you answer and I choose it as correct, I am a little noob in numpy,

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully this helps other folks in the future. Enjoy the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of an array is the number of elements, not bytes it contains. If your elements are all 57 bytes in size, then a 300x57 byte buffer is just the right size to initialize an array of size 300:

```
buff1_np = np.ndarray(300, dtype=onebuffdtype, buffer=shared_buff1.buf)
```